# PHP JSON Request Overload

Tags: php, json

On my [website](http://www.nbws.co.uk) I have a piece of php code that downloads some JSON and updates the site with what it says.

My site however is becoming more and more popular and I am close to reaching the limit on my api key. The data however only updates every ten minutes so I was thinking there must be a way to only allow the script to run every ten minutes but still produce the required text.

My php code:

```
<?php     
    $json_string = file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/MYKEY/conditions/q/pws:IENGLAND469.json");
    $parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
    $time = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'observation_time'}; //Take obs time string
    $windmph = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'wind_mph'};       //take wind speed
    $gustmph = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'wind_gust_mph'};   //take gust
    $dir = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'wind_dir'};
    $degs = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'wind_degrees'};
    $windknots = round($windmph/1.15078,1); //rounds and converts
    $gustmphflt = (float) $gustmph;         //float to string
    $gustknots = round($gustmphflt/1.15078,1); //round and convert
    if($windknots >27){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Wooooah!!</strong> Be careful super strong winds of ${windknots}</div>";
    }
    if ($windknots >16 AND $gustknots > 1.7*$windknots  ){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Wooooah!!</strong> Be careful it's gust out there!!</div>";
    }
    if($degs>80 AND $degs<200){
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Be Careful Offshore Wind!!</strong> The wind is offshore, blowing from ${dir}!</div>";
    }
?>
```

and:

```
<?php
    echo "<p> <!--From the ${dir} at-->   ${windknots} Knots gusting to ${gustknots} Knots<br>${time}</p>"; //print
?>
```

Comment: yes. Cache the response in a local file and only do a new lookup if the modified date is too far in the past.

Comment: @Dave I am a php newbie how would I apply that to my website

Comment: this should get you started: http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php

Comment: specifically this: http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php and this: http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php